# Returning value from PL/SQL block

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, mybatis

I need to return a value from a PL/SQL block in MyBatis.

The PL/SQL block is this:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    <foreach collection="params" item="param">
        UPDATE PRIORITIES
        SET PRIORITY = #{param.priority}
        WHERE ID = #{param.id};
    </foreach>
END
```

The reason I need to return a value, is that I want to be able to get the number of affected rows.

I know I could do it like this:

```
<update id="updateAll" parameterType="map">
    { call
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
        <foreach collection="params" item="param">
            UPDATE PRIORITIES
            SET PRIORITY = #{param.priority}
            WHERE ID = #{param.id};
        </foreach>

        #{affected_rows, jdbcType=DECIMAL, mode=OUT} := sql%rowcount;
    END
    }
</update>
```

But this means I must have a method like this in the java mapper:

```
public void updateAll(Map<String, String> parameters);
```

I have this instead:

```
public int updateAll(@Param("params") List<PriorityModel> model);
```

Is there a way to return that value without having a map?

Comment: sql%rowcount only applies to cursors loops. regarding your code you would get the rowcount of your last UPDATe only. But you can still accumulate the rowcount of each UPDATE into a variable.
However MyBatis-Update would be -1 since you calling a procedure.
You must use a parameter map and set the out-paramter as you already did.
If you want to keep your interface, you could use an inner service implementation. And in the actual implementation return the value of parameters.affected_rows

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't return a value from a procedure call. It's possible set a value in an object like a pojo or a map like your example but, i think if you at the same sql transaction execute a query after the updates like this:

```
SELECT sql%rowcount FROM DUAL;
```

You can get the number of affected rows like a ResultSet.

Comment: The question is about PL/SQL

Comment: I should have said, "`sql%rowcount` is not available in a SQL statement, even if that SQL statement is in a PL/SQL block."  For example, this block will not work: `declare v_number number; begin SELECT sql%rowcount into v_number FROM DUAL; end; /`
`

Comment: Ok, I will review the API doc to look for answers.